# Why does the Dropout with rate 0.0 in Keras not behave the same as no dropout?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a Deep Learning model built using Tensorflow's Keras API. The model gives 100% training and 95% test accuracy on my dataset. I am using `tf.random.set_seed`, which ensure that my results are reproducible.

Now, when I add a Dropout layer with rate 0.0, I expect the results to be the same. But instead it gives me a 97.69% training and 93.33% test accuracy.

Why is it so?

Doesn't a dropout rate of 0.0 mean 'No dropout'?

I am not sure if it helps, but my model looks like:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation=None, input_shape=(64, 64, 3)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation=None),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation=None),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128),
    # Dropout(0.0),
    Dense(6, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Where do you add the dropout layer? Do a sanity check, without the dropout rerun the previous code a few times to check if really your results are reproducible. There is a known bug https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10845

Comment: What is your Tensorflow version?